# Etags used in RESTful APIs are still susceptible to race conditions

Tags: python, database, rest, concurrency, etag

Maybe I'm overlooking something simple and obvious here, but here goes:

So one of the features of the Etag header in a HTTP request/response it to enforce concurrency, namely so that multiple clients cannot override each other's edits of a resource (normally when doing a PUT request). I think that part is fairly well known.

The bit I'm not so sure about is how the backend/API implementation can actually implement this without having a race condition; for example:

Setup:

- RESTful API sits on top of a standard relational database, using an ORM for all interactions (SQL Alchemy or Postgres for example).
- Etag is based on 'last updated time' of the resource
- Web framework (Flask) sits behind a multi threaded/process webserver (nginx + gunicorn) so can process multiple requests concurrently.

The problem:

- Client 1 and 2 both request a resource (get request), both now have the same Etag.
- Both Client 1 and 2 sends a PUT request to update the resource at the same time. The API receives the requests, proceeds to uses the ORM to fetch the required information from the database then compares the request Etag with the 'last updated time' from the database... they match so each is a valid request. Each request continues on and commits the update to the database.
- Each commit is a synchronous/blocking transaction so one request will get in before the other and thus one will override the others changes.
- Doesn't this break the purpose of the Etag?

The only fool-proof solution I can think of is to also make the database perform the check, in the update query for example. Am I missing something?

P.S Tagged as Python due to the frameworks used but this should be a language/framework agnostic problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a question about how to use ORMs to do updates, not about ETags.

Imagine 2 processes transferring money into a bank account at the same time -- they both read the old balance, add some, then write the new balance.  One of the transfers is lost.

When you're writing with a relational DB, the solution to these problems is to put the read + write in the same transaction, and then use SELECT FOR UPDATE to read the data and/or ensure you have an appropriate isolation level set.

The various ORM implementations all support transactions, so getting the read, check and write into the same transaction will be easy.  If you set the SERIALIZABLE isolation level, then that will be enough to fix race conditions, but you may have to deal with deadlocks.

ORMs also generally support SELECT FOR UPDATE in some way.  This will let you write safe code with the default READ COMMITTED isolation level.  If you google SELECT FOR UPDATE and your ORM, it will probably tell you how to do it.

In *both* cases (serializable isolation level or select for update), the database will fix the problem by getting a lock on the row for the entity when you read it.  If another request comes in and tries to read the entity before your transaction commits, it will be forced to wait.

Answer (score 1):

`Etag` can be implemented in many ways, not just `last updated time`.  If you choose to implement the `Etag` purely based on `last updated time`, then why not just use the `Last-Modified` header?

If you were to encode more information into the `Etag` about the underlying resource, you wouldn't be susceptible to the race condition that you've outlined above.

> The only fool proof solution I can think of is to also make the database perform the check, in the update query for example. Am I missing something?

That's your answer.

---

Another option would be to add a version to each of your resources which is incremented on each successful update.  When updating a resource, specify both the ID and the version in the `WHERE`.  Additionally, set `version = version + 1`.  If the resource had been updated since the last request then the update would fail as no record would be found.  This eliminates the need for locking.

Comment: In regards to your second paragraph , how would that solve the problem, can you give an example?

Comment: Certainly.  An Etag is really just a hash of a resource to later be used to identify whether or not the resource has changed.  If you were to hash a record in its entirety, then you could, in a transaction/blocking section, compare the hash provided by the user against the current record in the DB by simply hashing it with the same algorithm.

Comment: That is assuming that the database knows the same hash algorithm as the application, that then puts a dependants on the database implementation and couples the two together potentially.

Comment: The application should control the flow of data.  The database shouldn't be responsible for hashing.

Comment: That's what I am saving Evan but you seemed to suggest that it should in your previous comment.  Hashing the record in the application could still lead to races could it not?  Are you suggesting (write) locking the row of the database in the application for the entiry of the request?

Comment: Another option would be to version the data.  Anytime you go to update the underlying resource, you would add the constraint of `and version = xxx`.  If no record was updated, then you can assume that the record was updated since the client pulled the data.  In the context of the update, you would include `set version = version + 1`.

Comment: The version is basically a sequence number but this doesn't provide anything more than a last update time, apart from how many times it was updated since (which is not the problem).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98758/discussion-between-evan-and-metalstorm).

Answer (score 1):

You are right that you can still get race conditions if the 'check last etag' and 'make the change' aren't in one atomic operation.

In essence, if your server itself has a race condition, sending etags to the client won't help with that.

You already mentioned a good way to achieve this atomicity:

> The only fool-proof solution I can think of is to also make the database perform the check, in the update query for example.

You could do something else, like using a mutex lock. Or using an architecture where two threads cannot deal with the same data.

But the database check seems good to me. What you describe about ORM checks might be an addition for better error messages, but is not by itself sufficient as you found.